# Make a barchart from groupby table

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a table like this :

[image: Table from a group by]

so I want to make a bar chart with an x-axis = Partner and Dependents and y-axis = customerID (it is numeric from sum) and hue = Churn

I try it with this code :

```
dfp = df.pivot_table(index = ['Partner', 'Dependents'], columns = 'Churn', values = 'customerID').reset_index()

sns.barplot(y= 'No', x= 'Dependents', data = dfp, estimator = sum, hue = 'Partner')
```

and the result :

[image]

and what I want (I edit it in paint) :

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it? thanks

Comment: Demonstrate your effort in solving the problem at hand and where are you getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

What about just adding a variable which combines the two columns?

```
df['Partner, Dependents'] = df['Partner'] + ', ' + df['Dependents']
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Churn', y='customerID', hue='Partner, Dependents', estimator=sum)
```